# Check if a number appears in an array C++

Tags: c++

I took a coding sample test and I think it's really easy. They ask to find if a number appears in the array (print out YES) or not (print out NO). At first, I want  come up with binary search method. But when I see their given function, I think it's not suitable to use that method.

In the description, they mention arr[] and k as the number we need to check if k appears in arr[].

```
char* findNumber(int arr_count, int arr[], int k)
{
 int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
  for(arr_count = 0; arr_count < n; arr_count++)
  {
     if(arr[arr_count]==k)
       cout<<"YES";
     else
       cout<<"NO";
  }
  return 0;
}
```

But when I compiled, it showed the output is null. I don't know why? I solved many more difficult problems. So I feel so bad when I got error in an easy task like this. Please tell me the wrong part.

Comment: Consider what you print if the first item in the array doesn't match. Should the else be inside the loop or handled at the end once you have searched the whole array? Is there any reason to keep going once you've found the item? A binary search isn't appropriate for this task unless the array is sorted or is large enough that the cost of sorting it and binary searching is less than a linear search would normally be.

Comment: Why do you calculate the size of the array when they give it to you as the first parameter?

Comment: Also `char*` is the wrong return type for `return "YES";`, it should be `const char*`.

Comment: Oh and if they gave you this broken function signature, you probably want to find some other coding proficiency test.

Comment: This is a quick test. The system automatically counts down within 90 seconds to finish it. Due to that haste, I was getting silly on arr_count part.

Comment: `cout << "NO"` should be outside the loop

Comment: There's pretty much no need for loops in C++. Use [std::find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) instead, passing [std::begin](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [std::end](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) along with the value you are looking for: `auto const it{ find(begin(arr), end(arr), k) }; if (it != end(arr)) cout << "YES";`. And that's all there is to it.

Comment: @IInspectable :  I tried to use std::find in another test, but that function only works in new version (maybe C++17, not sure if C++14 can use it). So I couldn't use it.

Comment: `std::find` has been around since even before C++98. `std::begin` and `std::end` require C++14 when applied to array arguments. The latter are not required; you can pass pointers to the beginning and one element past the end of the array to `std::find` just as well.

Answer (score 3):

Here

```
char* (int arr_count, int arr[], int k) { }
```

Compiler changes `int arr[]` into `int *arr` that's because of [array decaying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying). So when you do

```
 int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
```

`sizeof(arr)` will be size of `int*` and `n` is always `1`.

Hence this

```
for(arr_count = 0; arr_count < n; arr_count++) {
   /*  some stuff */
}
```

iterates only once.

Comment: Can you tell me how to avoid array decaying? In my case, do I just need to modify to n = sizeof(arr) ?

Comment: @HectorTa Isn't that what `arr_count` is for?

Comment: @HectorTa If `arr_count` is the no of elements in the array, then use like  `for(int itr = 0; itr < arr_count ; itr++) {  }` and remove the `int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);` statement as its not needed in that case. And use `arr[itr]==k` in `if` condition.

Comment: @HectorTa - there is no way to prevent "array decaying".  It is a core feature of the language.   There are alternatives, such as using a standard container (e.g. `std::vector<int>`, which can provide information about how many elements it has) instead of a raw array.

Comment: @pet: You *can* prevent array-to-pointer decay by avoiding pointer types in the function signature. You can pass arrays by value or (const) reference. This requires that the array size is known at compile time.

Comment: @IInspectable  - an array (in the sense of something created using `SomeType array[some_size]`) cannot be passed by value.   It is also not possible to have a single function that can accept an array of arbitrary size by reference  (A templated function is possible, but that creates one instance of the function for every array size, and still requires the size to be known at compile time in order to use that template).   I'm not about to start encouraging an obvious newbie to use such things - too many pitfalls, and a standard container is a better alternative.

Comment: @pet: Stack Overflow isn't about the OP or their ability to digest an answer. It is about the question only. While true, that you cannot pass a language-level array by value, there is `std::array` to side-step the array-to-pointer decay (which, btw., is actively being discussed to be removed from the language). All of those options require that the array size be known at compile time, and an appropriate overload set exists that can take arbitrary array sizes. Function templates with non-type template arguments are the idiomatic solution here.

Answer (score 2):

> int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);

At least this is incorrect, as your array `arr` decays to a pointer when passing it to function.

So `sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0])` is actually `sizeof(pointer)/sizeof(int)`. And so `n` is always 1. And your `for` loop always runs for one iteration only (when arr_count == 0).

> for(arr_count = 0; arr_count < n; arr_count++)

This is also incorrect - as you are not supposed to modify `arr_count` which is the input array size. You should use a separate variable for the loop.

```
for( int i = 0; i < arr_count; ++i )
```

Comment: So I should edit n = sizeof(arr) ? I checked on geeksforgeeks website, they always do the same way. When can we use my declaration?

Comment: @HectorTa I think the size of the array is in the first parameter `arr_count`.

Comment: Usually when you pass an array, you pass it a pair of parameters: (array_itself, array_size). So yes as @Galik pointed out, arr_count is the array size in this case. The order of params seems to be reverse though.

Answer (score 1):

```
 #include<iostream>

 const char* findNumber(int arr_count, int arr[], int k)
 {

   for(int i = 0; i < arr_count ; i++)
   {
      if(arr[i]==k)
        return "YES";
   }
   return "NO";
 }

 int main()
 {
    int array[] = { 2,36,42,8,85,35,225,100};
    std::cout << findNumber(sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]),array,43) << std::endl;
    std::cout << findNumber(sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]), array, 85) << std::endl;
    return 0;
 }
```

there you go. fixed and working fine. outputs NO and then YES.